# Google Chrome issue with SSL

Tags: google, https, http, google-chrome

Using this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

My site goes to HTTPS if I type in www.domain.com. HOWEVER, only Google Chrome refuses to show my EV CERT and complains about mixed content. If I visit the site in HTTPS or jump pages because everything is set to HTTPS now in the links I don't have the problem. The green bar shows just fine.

Is this a bug with Google?

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely a BUG with Google, millions of sites use SSL without any problem. Your problem is likely because you have elements on the page that are not being transferred using SSL while some are...

Using Firebug or Similar look at 'NET' tab and refresh the page and check what resources are being loaded via HTTP and what is being loaded by HTTPS.

This mostly happens when using absolute paths i.e `<img src="http://www.domain.com/img.png" alt="" >` while using `<img src=/img.png>` will work for both HTTP and HTTPS.

Remote scripts can also throw up these errors, ensure all remote JavaScripts and other resources are either using `//domain.com/script.js` or `HTTPS://domain.com/script.js`. Additionally showing us the HTML or site in question goes a long away for giving you a more solid answer.

Using a global rewrite won't fix this issue, its time to go back and edit your content this time using `/` without http or with `https://`

Comment: Hey, I manually went in and changed EVERY http to https and Google Chrome will still give the issue when the site redirects to HTTPS but if I start off going to the HTTPS it works fine and shows the seal, so I am thinking that the redirect from http to https is the issue

Comment: @FrankThornton care to share the URL in question? what happens when you visit https:// without going to HTTP first.